# Ошибка подключения в Indy

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Код ошибки вот такой:

```
Error connecting with SSL.
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure.
```

**Какой бы тип sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1 не использую все равно ошибка!**

**Делаю вот так:**

```
Var
SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
HTTP: TIdHttp;
begin
  SSL:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Application);
  SSL.ReadTimeOut:=10000;
  ///sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1
  SSL.SSLOptions.Method:=sslvSSLv23;
  SSL.SSLOptions.Mode:=sslmUnassigned;

  HTTP:=TidHTTP.Create(Application);
  HTTP.ReadTimeout:=10000;
  HTTP.IOHandler:=SSL;
  HTTP.AllowCookies:=true;
  HTTP.Request.UserAgent :='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.54 Safari/537.36 OPR/36.0.2130.21 (Edition beta)'; //'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36';

  try
    memo1.lines.text:=HTTP.Get('https://zachestnyibiznes.ru/');
  finally
    SSL.Free;
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Этим же кодом: К примеру, код страницы https://www.e1.ru/ получаю без проблем.

**Куда копать и в чем может быть ошибка ?**

```
**Версия Indy:** 10.6.2.5341
**Версия RAD:** RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin Version 24.0.25048.9432
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ответ, "краем уха\пробегая мимо"
Вопрос: Проблема осталась? D обновляли? Win какая?
Вот примерно по дате вашего запроса - вроде как слышал, что было обновление сертификатов Ms\Googl + отсечение старых SSL методов в обозревателях.